# Avoid server certificate error when posting form via RCurl

Tags: r, post, curl, web-scraping, rcurl

I'm getting this certificate verification error when trying to post a form via `RCurl::postForm()`:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Not really familiar with POST forms yet, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

### Example that produced the error

I've looked at the source code of http://goo.gl/qOf5t and identified the POST form of the first flight listed (as of 2013-04-09 this is FFM - NY for 437,97 €):

```
<form data-carrier='["AF"]' method="post" target="_blank" action=
"https://www.fluege.de/flight/itinerary/sFlightInput/bd253d844ad40c38e2334930a849da76/SAB"
class="clearfix itinForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="2" /> <input type="hidden" name="recom"
  value="2" /> <input type="hidden" name="type" value="SAB" />

  <div class="relative clearfix">
    <div class="Pricebox PriceboxWO">
      <div class="spiffy spiffytop schemeh1">
        <div class="spiffy1">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="spiffy2">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="spiffy3">
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="spiffy4">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="PriceItin floatfix">
        <div class="fll">
          Preis p. P.&nbsp;:&nbsp;
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And then I fired this:

```
require("RCurl")
x <- RCurl::postForm(
    uri="https://www.fluege.de/flight/itinerary/sFlightInput/bd253d844ad40c38e2334930a849da76/SAB",
    .params=list(
        key=160,
        recom=160,
        type="SAB"
    ),
    style="POST"
)
```

Comment: Not yet ;-) Do I need that?

Comment: Yes.  You'll need to reinstall curl after installing OpenSSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From RCurl FAQ http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/FAQ.html

> Why does https not work for me?
>
> Probably because when you compiled/installed libcurl, you didn't have
>   support for SSL. You can check this with the command
>   `curl-config --feature`
>   If ssl doesn't appear there, you don't have support for it. You should reinstall curl, having first installed SSL (e.g. [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/)).

Answer (score 3):

From what I've read elsewhere, the problem seems to be that RCurl is no longer including any CA information.

Take a look at the following URL. You probably need to grab CA information from somewhere and install it locally.

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

With getURL you can set a parameter to ignore the certificate, but I have not found a way yet to do that with postForm.